# how to execute function when move scroll with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, scrollbar

I have one div that active overflow in it and I want when move scroll show me `scrollTop` in console but I can do it. please guide me.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: *"please guide me."* Bind a `scroll` event handler to the element and pass the return value of `scrollTop` to `console.log` inside the event handler. If you have a particular problem with that, then please post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, bind the window scroll and get the `scrollTop` from window

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    $('label').text($(this).scrollTop());
    console.log($(this).scrollTop());
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/U5suy/1/)